# DateTime format for the DateTime field in Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I am working on project where I need to migrate the date from one list to another. My Source list having DateTime format as MM/DD/YY and my destination list field having DateTime format as DD/MM/YY. When I parse value at destination it's conversion is not correct.

Code to read values from the list fields.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetURL);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, passWord);

ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
SP.ListCollection listCol = web.Lists;
ctx.Load(listCol);

SP.List list = listCollection.GetByTitle("ListTitle");

SP.CamlQuery camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "";

SP.ListItemCollection listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
ctx.Load(listItemCollection);

//Execute Query 
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (ListItem _item in listItemCollection)
{
    ctx.Load(_item,tmp => tmp.FieldValuesAsHtml);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var fieldValue in _item.FieldValuesAsHtml.FieldValues)
    {
        string _value  = fieldValue.Value; //for datetime field returning value as string
    }

}
```

Convert _Value to Datetime at destination list

```
    destItem["Date"]= Convert.ToDateTime(_value);
//date is getting changed as DateTime format is diffrent.
```

How can I get the DateTime format for the source list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. We can get DateTime Format using Regional Settings property.

```
ClientContext.Load(f_Web, website => website.RegionalSettings)
ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var format = f_Web.RegionalSettings.DateFormat;
```